# Confusion about the word 'dhamma'?

Tags: dhammas, translation

What does the word '*dhamma*' mean when the Buddha said '*sabbe dhamma annatta'.*

I am being confused here. I looked through the translation. It reads '**all conditioned/unconditioned things are not-self**'.

Isn't the word *sankara* used for conditioned things.

The word *dhamma* in my native language literally means '**religion**'. Also I checked Wikipedia for the word *dhamma*. The Wiki gives similar meaning as '*religion*' in context of **Hinduism** but not clear on Buddhist use of the word.

My question is whats translation of word '*dhamma*' and in what context is it used in line '*sabbe dhamma annatta'*?

Comment: [Here](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/interpretation-of-sabbe-dhamma-anatta/4666) there's an insightful discussion about the meaning of '*dhamma*' in the context of "*sabbe dhamma anatta*'. Kind regards!

Comment: For those (like me) who need to look these things up, this is from the [Dhammapada, XX, 277-9](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.20.budd.html)

Answer (score 2):

Dhamma encompasses sankhara[created] but it also encompases the cessation principle which is not included in sankhara as it is asankhata [not-created].

> Both formerly & now, it is only stress that I describe, and the cessation of stress."[sn22.86](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.086.than.html)

There are these famous lines;

```
 Sabbe sankhara anicca
 Sabbe sankhara dukkha
 Sabbe dhamma anatta
```

Translated;

```
 All formations are impermanent
 All formations are suffering
 All Dhamma [teachings] are not-self
```

Then reconciled with;

> Both formerly & now, it is only stress that I describe, and the cessation of stress."

It makes sense because;

1. Stress is part of the teaching [things that are taught]
2. Cessation of stress is part of the teaching [things that are taught]

The semantic referent of #2 is the unconditioned; is neither impermanent[anicca] nor suffering[dukkha]; but it is likewise not-self[anatta].

Answer (score 1):

Like sankhara, the term dhamma is very broad and means different things per different context. In the broadest sense, sankhara is a subset of dhamma, for dhamma includes not only conditioned phenomena/sankhara, but also unconditioned element/ASankhataDhatu, ie. Nibbana. See the Pali defitions for [Dhamma](http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/b_f/dhamma.htm) and [Sankhara](http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/s_t/sankhaara.htm) further details.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your description:

- *sankhara* means conditioned things / phenomena.
- *dhamma* means all things / phenomena i.e. both conditioned and unconditioned things / phenomena

What is unconditioned? Only *Nibbana* - it is that which is experienced by the mind, when it is completely free of all fetters and defilements.

What is conditioned? Everything else, including mental and physical phenomena / things.

"*sabbe sankhara dukkha*" means "all conditioned things/ phenomena are suffering / unsatisfactoriness". This does not include *Nibbana*.

"*sabbe sankhara anicca*" means "all conditioned things/ phenomena are impermanent". This does not include *Nibbana*.

"*sabbe dhamma anatta*" means "all things/ phenomena are not self". This includes *Nibbana*.

From AccessToInsight's [Glossary of Pali and Buddhist Terms](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/glossary.html):

> *dhamma* [Skt. *dharma*]:
> (1) Event; a phenomenon in and of itself;
> (2) mental quality; (3) doctrine, teaching; (4) *nibbāna*. Also,
> principles of behavior that human beings ought to follow so as to fit
> in with the right natural order of things; qualities of mind they
> should develop so as to realize the inherent quality of the mind in
> and of itself. By extension, "*Dhamma*" (usu. capitalized) is used also
> to denote any doctrine that teaches such things. Thus the *Dhamma* of
> the Buddha denotes both his teachings and the direct experience of
> *nibbāna*, the quality at which those teachings are aimed.
>
> *saṅkhāra*:
> Formation, compound, fashioning, fabrication — the
> forces and factors that fashion things (physical or mental), the
> process of fashioning, and the fashioned things that result. *Saṅkhāra*
> can refer to anything formed or fashioned by conditions, or, more
> specifically, (as one of the five *khandhas*) thought-formations within
> the mind.

Please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/31737/471) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Sabbe Dhamma Anatta is difficult to understand.... Here is my understanding.Dhamma roughly translates to religion. More precisely all teachings about what is. Is there a God ? Is there a suffering ? Are there emotions ? Are there forms ? Are there choices ? Is there consciousness ? Is there Universe ?Whatever there is can not be said to be me , mine or myself ... That is the meaning of Sabbe Dhamma Anatta ...