# Is nirvana a conceptual construction?

Tags: nirvana, sunyata

Is nirvana a conceptual construction - empty in that way? For any / only some Buddhists.

I'm just trying to figure out how extinction can avoid the extremes of eternalism and annihilation. If it is a conceptual construction in the sense of having no reality outside what it is in conventional designation (blissful etc.), that *might* be an answer. If some rock has no qualities that we cannot define, then maybe there is nothing to add to its existence, nothing to puzzle over and ask why or how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I'm just trying to figure out how extinction can avoid the extremes of eternalism and annihilation."

And therein lies your problem.  If you are trying to figure it out, you are dealing in concepts, not nirvana.  Every word you speak answers itself.  It is a closed loop.  A closed system.  Step outside.  How would you define a word without using language?  See the following:

> **Case 5 of the Mumonkan Kyogen's "Man Up a Tree"**
>
> The Case:
>
> Kyõgen Oshõ said, "It is like a man up in a tree hanging from a branch
> with his mouth; his hands grasp no bough, his feet rest on no limb.
> Someone appears under the tree and asks him, 'What is the meaning of
> Bodhidharma's coming from the West?' If he does not answer, he fails
> to respond to the question. If he does answer, he will lose his life.
> What would you do in such a situation?"
>
> Mumon's Comment:
>
> Even if your eloquence flows like a river, it is of no avail. Though
> you can expound the whole of Buddhist literature, it is of no use. If
> you solve this problem, you will give life to the way that has been
> dead until this moment and destroy the way that has been alive up to
> now. Otherwise you must wait for Maitreya Buddha and ask him.
>
> Mumon's Verse:
>
> Kyõgen is truly thoughtless;
>  His vice and poison are endless.
>  He stops
> up the mouths of the monks, 
>  And devil's eyes sprout from their
> bodies.

Instead of worrying about concepts, search for the word that has neither sound nor meaning.

Comment: really great answer, thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Is nirvana a conceptual construction? For any / only some Buddhists

Of course it'd depend on who you ask. To a deep-sea fish, the fresh breeze of the open sky will remain a conceptual construction, but to a man on land, that's something possible to have first-hand experience of. Similarly, Nibbana will remain a conceptual construction until one's attained awakening like the Buddha and His noble disciples.

Comment: so your answer is "no"? a reference would help you here

Comment: "no" and "yes", depending on the group of people already specified.

Comment: hm interesting. but you seem to also be saying that the buddha claimed unambiguously it isn't

Comment: Again, whether it is or is not depends on the frame of reference.

Comment: ok cool.   do  you have a quote  to support your claim that nirvana is not a conceptual construction to his noble disciples?

Comment: A simple quote will do no justice, you'll have to read the whole sutta to get the idea. Read MN 27: https://suttacentral.net/mn27/en/bodhi . Also please provide the exact reason or background to your inquiry ?

Comment: there is no reference to conceptual construction therein... dwai

Comment: You instantly replied, that indicates you have not read it. By the way, please answer my question.

Comment: ok done, right ?

Comment: done or not done, it's up to you. I can go on forever if you like.

Comment: sorry i'm not clear what you're talking about now

Comment: sorry, what is it that you meant "done"?

Comment: i edited my question, that's what i meant

Comment: From the way you interact, I'm not sure whether you're really serious in learning more, or just trolling. But either way, I'm still gonna do my part, which is to share infos, cuz if you don't read it, others will. Now, back to your added inquiry, there's already an excellent answer on dhammwheel, which you should check out: https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?p=576140#p576140

Comment: i think you have an attitude problem... no need to blame me

Comment: The problem is blatantly obvious in your alias, SATIRICAL_BUDDHIST

Comment: ok well i tried to change it but can't for another month or so. sorry

Answer (score 1):

When language is involved, everything becomes a conceptual construct. That's the problem with language, you have to create a concept of something to explain something. The question in itself is unclear, but Nirvana is a goal, or a state. It's a state of freedom from suffering and rebirth. When you reach nirvana, your mind is free from the 3 fires. The fires of ignorance/delusion, attatchment/greed and aversion/hate. You do not experience rebirth anymore, as you have removed the attachment to life.

Answer (score 0):

Nirvana or Nibbana is not a thought or concept of the mind. It is that which is experienced by the mind, when it is completely free of all fetters and defilements.

I quote from [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/31737/471) below. Please see that answer for a detailed analysis including sutta quotes.

> So, *Nibbana* is not a thought of the mind, not a concept of the mind,
> not a state of the mind, not a state of consciousness and also not a
> feeling. However, when the mind experiences this *Nibbana*, which is not
> conditioned, not compounded, not suffering, not impermanent, not
> arising, not ceasing and not changing, it experiences bliss. The mind
> can therefore experience *Nibbana*, but it cannot feel it or think about
> it.
>
> Sukha or *happiness* for an unenlightened person is experienced when
> encountering pleasant feelings (from the six senses) or when
> encountering the cessation of painful feelings (from the six senses).
> But for an *arahat*, *sukha* or bliss (in this context) is experienced
> when encountering neutral feelings, no feelings and *Nibbana*.

Also from that answer:
From [AN 9.34](https://suttacentral.net/an9.34/en/sujato) (translated by Bhikkhu Sujato):

> Ven: Sariputta: “Reverends, extinguishment (Nibbana) is bliss!
>
> Ven. Udayi: “But Reverend Sāriputta, what’s blissful about it, since
> nothing is felt?”
>
> Ven. Sariputta: “The fact that nothing is felt is precisely what’s
> blissful about it.

Comment: is that what conceptual construction means then -- a mere idea of empirical reality?

Comment: @satirical_buddhist It's simply the complete absence of *dukkha* (suffering / discontent).

Comment: of what though?

Comment: @satirical_buddhist If you read that answer, it quotes [AN 9.34](https://suttacentral.net/an9.34/en/sujato): Ven: Sariputta: “Reverends, extinguishment (Nibbana) is bliss! Ven. Udayi: “But Reverend Sāriputta, what’s blissful about it, since nothing is felt?” Ven. Sariputta: “The fact that nothing is felt is precisely what’s blissful about it."

Comment: i'm unconvinced that answers my question. which was not about happiness without feeling, but happiness wthout anything being happy

Comment: but i  can easily conceive of happiness without feelig. that is pretty standard religion / morality i think. not sure about happiness without a happy thing

Comment: @satirical_buddhist Nirvana is translated here as "extinguishment". That should give you a hint. It extinguishes everything that can make you unhappy, suffer or feel dissatisfied.

Comment: so are rocks happy?

Comment: @satirical_buddhist Rocks do not have feeling, perception, consciousness and mental formations. Plants do have feeling and maybe perception, but they do not have consciousness and mental formations. Only beings with all five aggregates who experience mental suffering, can attain Nirvana.

Comment: confusing. so the sentient being that undergoes nirvana is what is happy?

Comment: @satirical_buddhist The sentient being that attains Nirvana has found a stable source of happiness - the only stable source of happiness there is.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously people have conceptions about it (and those conceptions are conceptual constructions).

I think that nibbana itself is defined as unconstructed -- or [unconditioned](https://dhammawiki.com/index.php/33_synonyms_for_Nibbana) -- or more literally, "undefiled", "extinguished", etc., are among its [many attributes](https://suttacentral.net/sn43.14-43/en/sujato).

I think the idea is that because it isn't constructed, it is therefore not subject to decay and coming apart -- according to the "three characteristics", it's "sankharas" (i.e. constructed things) which are impermanent ... and nibbana isn't a sankhara.

I'm using "conditioned" and "constructed" here as synonyms, which perhaps isn't quite right, but I think it's along the right lines -- see also [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/35353/254) (which says that the non-construction of something may depend on some condition, but that what's unconstructed isn't itself impermanent).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. I have not experienced anything close to Nirvana. But from what Buddha has said we can understand it as a natural state of unborn , uncreate and as a state of unbecoming. It is grasped conceptually but once nirvana is achieved you don’t need to hold on to any concept. It is a natural state of unborn existence...

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about the referent of the word "nirvana"?

The referent of the word nirvana is a concept of nirvana, and the referent of that concept is ... WHAT?

The referent of that concept is the actual experiential liberation of the mind.

Liberation from what? Liberation from the confines of concepts and therefore from the dukkha that comes from the clash between concepts, or between the concepts on one hand and the ontological reality on the other.

Now you tell me, is this Liberation a conceptual construct? For you perhaps it is, because you are asking about it? For me - not anymore, because I attained it in practice.

Once attained, the concept of nirvana has no referent. One does not engage in semiotic games anymore. No bullshit like "nirvana" and "liberation".

Comment: Does the "reference/referent" duality exist in Buddhism, or is that (perhaps like "ideal/real") an artefact of western philosophy?

Comment: i think we can do without bragging about attainment, but thank you for the answer

Comment: @ChrisW it's a common feature of Tibetan Mahayana treatises, it comes up quite a lot.

Comment: It seemed to me refreshingly absent in the suttas -- with that absence being a welcome (and radical) simplification -- albeit perhaps implied by "conceptual proliferation" or some things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Some aspects of Nagarjuna’s Madhyamaka-karika could suggest that, but that is not the “orthodox” Madhyamika stance, at least amongst Tibetans